"Invalid string length" error when trying to loop through the JS object
I'm very new to programming and right now I'm trying to build my first app. It is a daily expenses tracker. The part I'm struggling with is: when user adds a new item (for example, coffee) and an amount, a new div is supposed to be created which includes item and amount. And every time user adds a new item and amount, a new div should be created. I'm trying to implement this with a for loop, but when running the code I get "Invalid string length" error. Maybe there is another way to implement this logic or how could I fix my code? I'm using Node JS, Express and EJS.
EJS code snippet:
<div class = "add-new-item">
            <div class = "add-item">
                <form class= "item" action = "/add-new-item" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Item" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" />
                    <input type="text" name="newAmount" placeholder="Amount" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" />
                    <button type="submit" value="Add" id="addBtn">+</button>            
                </form>                   
            </div>
        </div>   

        <%if (locals.item && locals.amount) {%>
            <%let items = [];%>
            <%items.push({item, amount});%>
            <%console.log(items);%>

            <%for(let i = 0; i = Object.keys(items).length; i++) {%>
                <div class = "new-item">
                    <div class = "item">
                        <%= item %>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class = "amount">
                        €<%= amount %> 
                    </div>
                </div>%>
            <%}%>
            <% };%>

JS code snippet:
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));



app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.post("/add-new-item", async (req, res) => {
  const item = req.body.newItem;
  const amount = req.body.newAmount; 
  
  res.render("index.ejs", {item: item, amount: amount});
  
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Can you reduce the code to a [mcve]? I'm pretty sure, the server isn't necessary. You can render a EJS template without server. Which line does produce the error? What are the input values?

This is happening very likely because of i = Object.keys(items).length in the for loop. The syntax for a for loop is (MDN docs):
for (initialization; condition; afterthought)
  statement

So the second parameter, which is a condition, asks for a boolean. But instead you gave it an assignment to the variable i, so as a condition it checks the value you are assigning to i and Object.keys(items).length will always result in true if not 0. Not only that, it also assigns the length to i for each loop. Here's a small example on what you are doing (here is a demo, since you cannot even run this in most web environments):
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i = 0; i = a.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

With this, you also kind of made an infinite loop, the only thing that stops it is the "invalid string length" error.
To fix the loop, you want to change it to something like:
<%for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {%>
// or
<%for(let i = 0; i <= items.length - 1; i++) {%>

But the whole code logic doesn't seem to be doing what it is intended for anyway, since there is just 1 object present in the items array every time.
From what I can see in your code, it goes something like:

GET on route "/" which will render index.ejs
User adds an item in the form there which will POST on "/add-new-item"
Handler for the "/add-new-item" route then renders index.ejs again but passes an object as data that holds 1 item and 1 amount variable
ejs renders the template, so it creates the empty items array and pushes that one object

But ultimately, this means that the items are never stored anywhere and if we were to add a new item after what we're doing in the list above, the entire process would be repeated. So in the end, it would just replace the other item and there would always be just a single item present.
Instead, what you should do, is when the user adds an item, send a fetch request to the server. The handler on the server then adds the item and amount to either an array stored on the server or to a database. Subsequently you can either send an array containing all items back to the fetch API, let ejs render the part inside the for loop again with the new values and insert it to the DOM (requires ejs on the client side) or you render the html on the server and just send that back. Then you can modify the route handler that renders index.ejs, so you can just always pass the array of items (either already present on the server or always get it from the DB before sending it) as data. If it's empty, nothing will be rendered inside the for loop and if it has values those will be rendered.
Generally speaking, you rarely define variables in ejs tags and if you do, they are most likely small route dependent variables, something like the page title. I hope this helps, feel free to ask more if you need help :)
